# Xamarin.Forms iOS app crashes in ListView after update to Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.231

Tags: xamarin.forms.listview

The app is a Xamarin.Forms PCL app running version 2.3.4.231 after an upgrade from Xamarin.Forms v2.2.0.31. The app works just fine on my iPhone 6s running version 10.2.1, however the app crashes on the ListView page when running on my iPad Mini 2 running version 7.1.2. More importantly, neither Xamarin Insights or HockeyApp catches the error.

The app worked just fine with the old version of Xamarin.Forms when both Windows 10 and my Mac Book was running this version of the software. https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-6-service-release-4/

I just upgraded both Windows 10 and my Mac Book to this version of the software. https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.4/

I'm now getting this error in the iOS properties section.

[image: Image showing error]

It might be important to note that I'm using this in the ListView page. Both packages are installed in the Portable and iOS Projects.
Xamarin.FFImageLoading v2.0.5
Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms v2.0.5

I'm just assuming this has something to do with ListView, but I have no idea other than this is where the app is crashing. Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if you need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 and 8 are no longer supported according to this link. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/630

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4 or newer, versions older than iOS 7 are no longer supported. You can see the official documentation here, under "Other Changes"

https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-xamarin-forms-2-3-4-224/

It does appear iOS 8 and newer are still supported however.